# changing integer value in dataframe column to string

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to change a column that currently has integer values that represent the difference in price. I want to change them so that values greater than 0 say 'Bigger' and less than 0, 'Smaller'.

I tried: `month['Difference'] = np.where((month.Difference > 0.0),'Bigger',month.Difference)`

But get an error: `'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
month['Difference'] = np.where((month['Difference'].astype(float) > 0),'Bigger',month.Difference)
```

Maybe it is better not to overwrite your existing column so create a new column

```
month['new_difference'] = np.where((month['Difference'].astype(float) > 0),'Bigger',month.Difference)
```

If you don't have zero values

```
month = pd.DataFrame({'Difference':[1,2,3,4,-1,-1]})

month['new_difference'] = np.where((month['Difference'].astype(float) > 0),'Increase','Decrease')
```

Comment: Thank you! That has gotten rid of the error. Although, I tried to apply the same to the 'Smaller' values but then the values that were previously written as 'Increase' have returned back to their initial numerical values, and I am left with 'Smaller'. Any idea how to apply both conditions? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Hey willyg changed the answer does this help you? Please upvote if it does ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, your final line worked for me! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Great to hear. Can you set your question as answered ;)?

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your column values are currently regarded as a string.

I believe using `.apply()` will best suit your use case:

```
def difference_to_string(diff):
    if float(diff) > 0.0:
       return "Bigger"
    else:
       return "Smaller"

month['Difference'] = month['Difference'].apply(difference_to_string)
```

Alternatively, you could convert the entire column to float type by

```
month['Difference'] = month['Difference'].astype(float)
```

and your method should work.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: My pleasure! :)